# Why ghostscript is a required dependency for cups?

Tags: printing, ghostscript, cups

[cups 2.2.2-1ubuntu1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/cups) depends on ghostscript, however if I understood correctly ghostscript is a PDF/PS interpreter that is required the we send a PDF/PS to CUPS but the printer doesn't support neither of this formats.
[For example](http://pig.made-it.com/printing.html#1773) for printers that provide CUPS driver (aka Raster driver):

[image]

But what if I have a PS printer, then no filter is needed and ghostscript should not be invoked.

Why add a dependency to a **non free software** (correct me if I'm wrong but AFAIK ghostscript is dual AGPL/Commercial Licence) that is not needed for simple cases?

### UPDATE

From [OpenPrinting](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/start)

> [...] the upstream standard for CUPS under Linux (using CUPS plus our cups-filters package) is the PDF-based job processing [...]. Only exception is if the input data is PostScript and the printer is a PostScript printer or the printer driver requires PostScript as input. Then **we do not turn PostScript into PDF and back into PostScript** but pass the PostScript through the pstops filter as before.

Comment: Ghostscript is indeed dual licenced. I can't really see how that's a problem since one of the licenses is AGPL. And if you need to process PostScript, then you need a PostScript interpreter, good luck with finding another (complete level 3) one. AIUI CUPS internally converts everything to PDF, passes the PDF through the filters and then converts the PDF to 'printer format' at the end. SO if you take PostScript, and send it to a PostScript printer, it still gets converted to PDF in between (caveat: I could be wrong, I'm not a CUPS expert)

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your comment about converting PS to PDF (but I'm neither a CUPS expert so I could be wrong too). About *finding another PostScript interpreter* that is not what I'm looking for, I just want to understand if Ghostscript is a must in CUPS or some cases could avoid it. Maybe I've misunderstood the AGPL licence and there is no problem in using Ghostscript as long as I don't modify the source code.

Comment: Even if you modify the Ghostscript source code you are fine with **using** Ghostscript. Though obviously all open-source authors would like people to supply feedback and improvements! You would only run into licencing problems if you were supplying a product or service which used Ghostscript. I realise that's a bit nebulous, but I'm pretty certain that using it in a print service would not be regarded as infringing for example. In the same way that you are (presumably) using Linux, which is also GPL licenced.

Comment: Now, regarding CUPS, your post makes it likely that CUPS isn't turning PostScirpt into PDF. All the same, how is CUPS to know that your specific installation does not (and never will) use PostScript->PDF or PDF->PostScript ? For full functionality of the software you need all the dependencies, even if your specific use case won't actually use them.

Comment: But what about supplying a commercial product that doesn't know nothing about Ghostscript but sends printing jobs to a CUPS server that uses Ghostscript?.
About my specific installation don't using PS -> PDF or PDF -> PS, AIUI if CUPS doesn't find a filter to convert a input mime type to another specific mime type it just fails in runtime saying that it doesn't find a way to convert the input format.

Comment: But CUPS itself is licensed under the GPL. And again, if you are using software internally then you are free to use the GPL licensed versions. In your scenario clearly you are not providing the 'CUPS' service to your customer, you are providing them with printed output. It doesn't matter to your customer how you do that. In any event I think we've about reached the limit of what I can tell you, and I'm not in any way responsible for the CUPS distribution. From what you say if you don't have GS then it will all be fine for you, so just remove GS. But remember CUPS is GPL too......

Comment: Thanks for the help @KenS